# JNDI configuration/lookup in Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I'm having trouble getting some basic JNDI configuration going in Glassfish.

I have what I think ought to be a simple task: at run time, determine if a particular property is set to true or not.  I think this is a good application of JNDI, but can't seem to get the path correct between the app server and my servlet code.

Here's how I have configured the property in Glassfish:

[image]

In my servlet code, I'm trying to look up the value with:

```
Boolean enabled = (Boolean) ctx.lookup("java:global/arizona/quartz_enabled");
```

In addition to this path, I've also tried the following without success:

- java:global/arizona/arizona/quartz_enabled
- java:module/arizona/quartz_enabled
- java:module/arizona/arizona/quartz_enabled

My app is named "arizona", but deployed to the root context, if that matters.

I'm sure it's just a simple matter of figuring out the proper namespace to reach the property, but I feel like I'm just shooting in the dark trying to find it. Is there a simple way to browse the JNDI tree in Glassfish?

Answer (score 4):

When looking up a JNDI resource created in the server, it's JNDI name is exactly what you entered as the name on the server.   IE:

Boolean enabled = (Boolean)ctx.lookup("arizona");

For conventions on JNDI names and some example code on how to look everything up see this page:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2000/jw-01-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations, I simply place a breakpoint where object (`InitialContext` in this case) is instantiated and evaluate it afterwards. IntelliJ IDEA has [nice evaluator](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/debugger-evaluate-expression-enhancements/), not sure about other, arguably inferior, IDEs.

Btw, the correct prefix for all Java EE bindings is `java:comp/env/`, e.g. `java:comp/env/arizona/quartz_enabled`.

You might also want to look at [this resource](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/compdependencies_xmlforum_nov15.pdf).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work for me. I still get: Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/arizona/quartz_enabled' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/arizona/quartz_enabled]
I'm also an Intellij user, and that evaluator is indeed nice, but unfortunately in this case you still seem to need to know the proper JNDI name. I didn't see anything "walkable" in the InitialContext that I could navigate through.

Comment: In one of the appservers I needed to do debugging on (can't remember which exactly, t'was long time ago), the JNDI was implemented as a nested map, where keys are strings and values are either real (bound) values or maps (for nested paths). So I was able to cast it to a map and dig to the point I needed. InitialContext also has getEnvironment() method which returns Hashtable, so if Glassfish JNDI is not built on Map, it should still expose similar API. You can start from java:comp/env, see what's in it and dig until you find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make it work with `javax.naming.InitialContext#lookup` but injecting resource with

```
@Resource(name = "arizona/quartz_enabled")
private Boolean enabled;
```

works just fine.