# Share/access resources between Java EE server and web application

Tags: java

I'm searching the best way to communicate informations between my Java EE server (Glassfish V3) and my Java EE application (modules : web, jpa, ejb).

Why am I looking for that ?

I'm developing a Server Authentication Module (`SAM`) to plug in Glassfish and substitute the "classic" `realm`. My `SAM` can only access the `httpServletRequest` object so the basic way is to store data on `session`, access it under the `SAM` and autenthicate user via credentials stored into basic object. But this object have to be shared between `SAM` and application.

I'm just wondering if my `SAM` could access `singleton EJB` or `stateless EJB` belonging to my app ? My `SAM` is completely uncoupled of my app but is there a way to do this please ?

Comment: JNDI? This might help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/debu-testability-of-ejb-095455.html

Comment: I've always heard that JNDi is very slow. For authentication module (which is called on every request), is it the right choice ?

Comment: I don't really know sorry. Would have posted an answer instead of a comment if i did ;)
EDIT: This link looks more appropiate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278829/jndi-configuration-lookup-in-glassfish